# lwc combo box is not loading any values

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am pulling values form apex method to display in the lightning combo box. I get 500 internal server error from the console log and i see the method name and class name are correct. Not sure where i am missing.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getDivisions from '@salesforce/apex/TrafficReportController.getDivisions';

export default class TrafficHistoryReport extends LightningElement {
    @track divisionvalue = '';   
    @track Divisionvalues = [];
    @wire(getDivisions) 
    ListDivisions({data,error}){
        if(data){ 
            for(let i=0;i < data.length;i++){
                this.Divisionvalues.push({
                    label: data[i],
                    value: data[i]
                });
            }
            //this.divisionoption = this.Divisionvalues;
        }
        else if (error){
            window.consolde.log(error);
        }
    }

    get divisionoption() {
        //console.log(this.Divisionvalues);
        return this.Divisionvalues;
    }

    handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('value'+event.target.value)
    }

}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class TrafficReportController {
    public TrafficReportController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)    
    public static List<String> getDivisions(){
       List<Division__c> LstDivisions = [Select id, Name from Division__c];
       List<String> Lststrings = new Lststrings();
       for(Division__c Div:LstDivisions){
           Lststrings.add(Div.Name);
       }
       return Lststrings;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>Traffic History Report</div>
    <div>
        <lightning-combobox name="Divisions" label="Divisions" placeholder="Select a Division" value={divisionvalue} options={divisionoption} onchange={handlechange}></lightning-combobox>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: I'm sure there's more to the error message aside from a simple 500 internal error. Check the Chrome console (dig into the object spit out) and set up user debugs / trace flags for the dev console for logs coming out of the dev console.

Comment: I had the List<String> Lststrings = new Lststrings(); defined wrong and VScode did not error. Also i was trying to test in local development environment. I tried to deployed in my org and the error came up. I was able to fix this issue. Now a new issue is duplicate item in the combo box. Need to figure iout how to save Label and ID in value so that each dropdown is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the list every time you get a new set of data (wire events can trigger more than once).

```
@wire(getDivisions) 
ListDivisions({data,error}) {
    if(data){ 
        this.Divisionvalues = data.map(record => ({ label: record.Name, value: record.Id }));
    } else {
        window.consolde.log(error);
    }
}
```

You *should* be using ID values instead of the name for the options:

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)    
public static Division__c[] getDivisions(){
   return [Select id, Name from Division__c];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to have a dynamic combo box using this combo box value. Can you please provide me some reference on how to do it?

Comment: Debug log shows the query is executed in the backend but in the front end, i see the list populated only if i navigate to different tab and come back. on load the list does not show any value.

Comment: @Rajesh Do not use "push", or it may not work. Note specifically I use Array.map instead to convert the values to a new Array and assign it to the attribute. This triggers a rerender and allows the values to show immediately.

Comment: it worked. Thanks.